# Java: Why Program Skip Char Input?

Tags: java, exception

Java Skip First Character Input When Program Catch the Exception?

```
System.out.println("Enter Character:");
f = s.next().charAt(0);
```

Program Code:

```
    public class Main {
            public static void main(String[] args) {
             int num;
             char f = 'y';
              Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);               

                do {
                    try {
                    System.out.print("Enter Number:");
                    num = s.nextInt();


                    catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                    System.out.println("False=> This is Not Integer");
                }
            System.out.println("Enter Character:");
            f = s.next().charAt(0);

            while(f != 'y' && f !='n') {
            System.out.println("Press 'y' or 'n'");
            f = s.next().charAt(0);
        }
        }
           while(f == 'y');
           System.out.print("Print:" + f);
       }
       }
```

Compiler Output:

```
    Enter Number:ghjgh
    False=> This is Not Integer
    Enter Character:(Compiler Skip This Input)
    Press 'y' or 'n'
    n
    Print:n
```

Why Does this Happening. I don't know why, it skips the input data on exception catch.

Comment: Add `s.nextLine()` after scanning the number i.e. after `num = s.nextInt()`

Comment: @dev When User Enter Wrong Input In Number Which is First Input And Program try to catch this then it skip the second Input and direct goes to third input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `s.nextLine()` after scanning the number

```
...
try {
    System.out.print("Enter Number:");
    num = s.nextInt();
}
catch (InputMismatchException e) {
    System.out.println("False=> This is Not Integer");
}
s.nextLine();
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use instanceof keyword, Also like this:

```
try{
    String input = s.nextInt();
    int num = Integer.parseInt(input);
    // if execute here input is number
}catch(Exception e){
    // if execute here input is not number
    System.out.println("Please input number!");
}
```